# How to use a custom OpenID Connect provider created on the Portal inside a Custom Policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have configured a built-in policy with an OpenIdConnect provider (which is an Azure AD):
[image]
It works fine (I can connect with my account, first time the account is created).
Now, I have created a custom policy also with an OpenIdConnect provider with the exact same parameters (linked to the same Azure AD).
But when I test the custom policy, it creates a new account, it ignores the account already created by the built-in policy. But this is the same Azure AD behind!
What I'd like to achieve is to make the custom policy using the provider created on the Azure Portal.
Do you think this is possible?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi @Sylvain. You have to ensure that the issuer ID and issuer user ID that are mapped in the custom policy match that for the user account that is created by the built-in flow. Otherwise, the custom policy won't find the user account that was created by the built-in flow.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for your answer, makes sense. Could you give me some technical advices about how to achieve that please? I see the issuer user ID is the claim called "issuerUserId" (that one was easy ^^), but I'm not sure about the issuer ID. I think it can be either the claims "iss" or "idp", but the "iss" one is the same for both policies. So it may be "idp" claim, but how can I change it? Thanks!

Comment: Ok from what I understand, the key must be the OutputClaimTransaformation called "CreateAlternativeSecurityId", which is based on the issuerUserId and the identityProvider InputClaims. So makes sense, but the identityProvider is then "outputed" as "iss", but as I said, this claims has the same value for both policies... I'm getting lost now...

Comment: Hi @Sylvain. When it creates two different accounts, what is different in the `userIdentities` property for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to @Chris Padgett I got the answer!
So first, using the AD Graph API I was able to compare the userIdentities and see that "issuer" property was not the same:
[image]

So I made a quick investigation and discovered the Metadata url was different between the 2 policies:
//login.microsoftonline.com/979fb787-2d8f-4dbc-83cd-876dc7f9b550/.well-known/openid-configuration which gives this:
[image]

And //login.microsoftonline.com/979fb787-2d8f-4dbc-83cd-876dc7f9b550/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration which gives this:
[image]

The issuers are not the same! So all I have to do is to change the metadata url for one policy and it works!